# How to add audio input to video FFMPEG

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

please note that I'm really really new to these things, I'm streaming a blank black video with text as you can see here:

```
ffmpeg -re -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=360x360 -vf drawtext="fontfile='/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSerifBold.ttf': \ text='Testing VPS Live Stream': fontcolor=white: fontsize=20: box=1: boxcolor=black: \ x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h-line_h)/2" -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -maxrate 100k -bufsize 300k -f flv rtmp://streamurl/live/mykey
```

How could i add a audio file to this stream ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=360x360 -i audiofile -vf drawtext="fontfile='/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSerifBold.ttf': \ text='Testing VPS Live Stream': fontcolor=white: fontsize=20: box=1: boxcolor=black: \ x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h-line_h)/2,realtime" -af arealtime -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -maxrate 100k -bufsize 300k -f flv rtmp://streamurl/live/mykey
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this out, will audio file will be looped after its reached end ?

Comment: No, If you need that, add `-stream_loop -1` before `-i audiofile` and make sure you're using a recent git build of ffmpeg.

Comment: For some reason i hear no audio :/

Comment: Share full command and log.

Comment: Now I've tried to stream from mp4 wich has audio, no sound either,

Comment: ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i 1.mp4 -vf drawtext="fontfile='/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSerifBold.ttf': \ text='Testing VPS Live Stream': fontcolor=white: fontsize=20: box=1: boxcolor=black: \ x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h-line_h)/2,realtime" -af arealtime -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -b:a 160k -preset veryfast -maxrate 100k -bufsize 300k -f flv rtmp://mylive

Comment: Update: Oh, its just started to work after i added acc lines tho, maybe there were latency

Comment: Looks like an issue at the receiving end

Comment: Thank you for your time Gyan, I'm still very new in this field :)

Comment: By the way thanks for this: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/18377/infinite-video-loop-in-ffmpeg